# View file diffs in merge commits

Tags: magit

When I open the commit view for a regular commit in `magit`, I can see the diff for each file. When I open a merge commit, I can only see a summary of the number of lines that were changed. Is there a way to get the first behavior for merge commits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When viewing a merge commit or while hovering it in the log, press `d r <RET>` to open a diff view showing all the changes.

Comment: I have not yet accepted this answer because I am hoping that someone knows of a better way, preferably a configuration that changes the default behavior.

Comment: The reason you don't see any changes is that magit calls `git show` with `--cc`.  See `man git-diff-tree` for a description of how these flags compress the patch output. Your solution diffs against the first parent and is the simplest way of seeing what changes were brought in by the merge.  You may also want to modify the range to diff against the second parent.